# Remove empty <p></p> tags from html String in Swift

Tags: html, ios, regex, swift

I am trying to remove empty `<p></p>` tags from my string whose content is html. I have tried to use regex such as;

```
let deleteRegex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<p[^>]*><\\/p[^>]*>", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.allZeros, error: nil)
deleteRegex?.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(comment.text!, options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros, range: NSMakeRange(0, (comment.text! as NSString).length), withTemplate: "")
```

However i got no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use jquery.. $('htmlstring').find('p').remove()

Comment: I would like to do it in client Side. Thanks anyway @raghavendra.

Comment: I dont want to remove whole html tags if you read my question. @EricD.

Comment: The link was more for the comments over there than for the answer itself, actually... :)

Comment: Use `(?i)</?p\\b[^<]*>` to match all opening and closing `p` tags.

Comment: The duplicate was not about removing specific text from a longer text and had no hints on how to solve the current issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following snippet to remove all empty `p` tags:

```
var string = "Text here<p class=\"myclass\"></p> and here<p></p>"
let str = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(?i)<p\\b[^<]*>\\s*</p>", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)
print(str)
```

You do not need to escape `/`, but a word boundary will make sure you match `p` tag as a whole word. `[^<]*` will match arbitrary attributes. `\\s*` will match optional whitespace between opening and closing `p` tags.

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA3yF5/1)

Comment: `[^<]` should be `[^>]`. The result is the same in this case, but `[^>]` should be relatively fast.

Comment: @rintaro: I would use it several years ago, too, but `>` does not have to be xmlified, and `<` should always be. Thus, for safety reasons, I always prefer `[^<]*` to check whether we are inside a node.

Comment: @stribizhev I see. Thanks for explaination :)

Answer (score 1):

Please use this pattern to remove
the p tag:

```
"(?i)<p[^>]*>"
```